# Linq JOIN on a strongly typed dataset where comparator contains DbNull throws exception

Tags: .net, linq, join, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

Consider the query:

```
Dim orgs = From g In dbDS.gi_game
            Join o In dbDS.gi_organisation On g.DeveloperID Equals o.ID
            Select o
```

This will throw an exception when `g.DeveloperID` is DBNull (this is by design - changing DBNull to any other value is not an option):

`System.Data.StrongTypingException: 'The value for column 'DeveloperID' in table 'gi_game' is DBNull.'`

I tried this:

```
Dim orgs = From g In dbDS.gi_game
            Join o In dbDS.gi_organisation On g.DeveloperID Equals o.ID
            Where Not g.IsDeveloperIDNull
            Select o
```

But hit the same error upon the query enumeration. How do I control for dbnulls?

UPDATE:

Thanks to Shaybakov's answer below, problem solved by mixing linq and lambda. vb.net code:

```
Dim orgs = From g In dbDS.gi_game.Where(Function(x) x.IsDeveloperIDNull = False)
            Join o In dbDS.gi_organisation On g.DeveloperID Equals o.ID
            Select o
```

Comment: Can you switch the C# tag to vb.net?

Comment: you could add a where clause to exclude those records

Comment: If you want to answer your own question, post an answer rather than editing the answer into the question. You'll get upvotes too..

Comment: To be fair, Shaybakov answered the question - that's why I marked his as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c# syntax

```
From g In dbDS.gi_game.Where(x=>!x.IsDeveloperIDNull())
        Join o In dbDS.gi_organisation On g.DeveloperID Equals o.ID
        Select o
```

Comment: Brilliant - thank you. I would never have thought to mix Linq with Lambda. That opens up a whole new world of possibilities! I've put the vb.net code in my OP.